# Build mono for detecting runtime memory leakcage (in sources) for Linux

Tags: c#, mono

I had some problems with mono on linux. My application, which was build with c# on windows doesn't leak, but with mono I have different situation. After searching mono site I found [this post](https://www.mono-project.com/docs/advanced/runtime/memory-leaks/), I [build](https://github.com/mono/libgdiplus) and install it (without asan). After I downloaded [mono sources](https://download.mono-project.com/sources/mono/), used mono 5.8. And build It with flags for detecting memory leakage and set path :

```
# Ensure that all required packages are installed.
sudo apt-get install git autoconf libtool automake build-essential gettext cmake python
./autogen.sh --prefix=/usr/local --with-malloc-mempools=yes
make get-monolite-latest
make
make install
```

After building and installing, I run My application with 
`mono --profile=malloc:log-malloc ATS_RW_PTD.exe`

And get result:
The 'malloc' profiler wasn't found in the main executable nor could it be loaded from 'mono-profiler-malloc'.

I can't understand where I'm wrong and which profile I have to use. Is it step by step instruction for runtime memory leakage detection in mono?

Comment: And forgot, I did all of it on ubuntu 18.04 not osx.

Comment: You shouldn't use Mono now. Can you switch to .NET Core?

Comment: No, there is no way, I use it in embeded system with buildroot, And most part of code are used for mono.